# Mathematics subject GRE - getting raw score from scaled score

Tags: mathematics, gre

I took the April 2023 exam. I have a scaled score. How do I convert it to a raw score?  I hear there is no negative marking for skipped or incorrect questions.

Comment: Do they not report the raw score to the exam taker anymore?  They did to me many years ago.

Comment: Change of frame: why do you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I convert it to a raw score?

These conversions are different for every instance of the test, and the chart is not released. So, there is no way to find out exactly how many questions you answered correctly. For an approximate conversion, there is [this](https://www.mathsub.com/wp-content/uploads/2019-mathsub-conversion-chart.pdf) chart.

> I hear there is no negative marking for skipped or incorrect questions.

This is correct, and a recent change.

All this information, and more, is available on [the ETS website](https://www.ets.org/gre/test-takers/subject-tests/scores/understand-scores.html).